# "decide appointment", "fix appointment" or some other?

Tags: word-choice

I'm willing to say "The start time of the appointment has been decided long time ago. So, It can not be changed"

In idiomatic English, are the following sentences the same as what I want to say?

> The appointment has been fixed long time ago. So, ...
>
> The appointment has been decided long time ago. So, ...
>
> The appointment has been set long time ago. So, ...

I appreciate if you could tell me more simple or natural (idiomatic) way to tell that. I think it's common and often in business.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use "has been". "Was" would be more appropriate. Also, one would not typically say an appointment was "fixed" or "decided" unless it was in a particular context, instead it is "made" or "scheduled". For example:

- "The appointment **was made** a long time ago..."
- "The appointment
  **was scheduled** a long time ago..."

Comment: made is definitely way ahead... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=made+an+appointment%2Carranged+an+appointment%2C+scheduled+an+appointment&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmade%20an%20appointment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carranged%20an%20appointment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscheduled%20an%20appointment%3B%2Cc0